# How to handle the error of entering an invalid command on the framework for creating telegram bots on Rust - teloxide

Tags: rust, error-handling, telegram, telegram-bot

The teloxide documentation has an example of a bot with 3 commands.

```
use teloxide::{prelude::*, utils::command::BotCommands};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    pretty_env_logger::init();
    log::info!("Starting command bot...");

    let bot = Bot::from_env();

    Command::repl(bot, answer).await;
}

#[derive(BotCommands, Clone)]
#[command(rename_rule = "lowercase", description = "These commands are supported:")]
enum Command {
    #[command(description = "display this text.")]
    Help,
    #[command(description = "handle a username.")]
    Username(String),
    #[command(description = "handle a username and an age.", parse_with = "split")]
    UsernameAndAge { username: String, age: u8 },
}

async fn answer(bot: Bot, msg: Message, cmd: Command) -> ResponseResult<()> {
    match cmd {
        Command::Help => bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, Command::descriptions().to_string()).await?,
        Command::Username(username) => {
            bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, format!("Your username is @{username}.")).await?
        }
        Command::UsernameAndAge { username, age } => {
            bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, format!("Your username is @{username} and age is {age}."))
                .await?
        }
    };

    Ok(())
}
```

How can this example handle an invalid command entered by the user or, for example, when entering the /usernameandage command, more parameters than just `username` and `age`

If these errors cannot be handled in any way, then how else can you issue commands in teloxide?

Answer (score 0):

I just started with teloxide myself

i guess a way to do it would be like that:

```rust
...

let bot = Bot::from_env();

    Dispatcher::builder(
        bot,
        dptree::entry()
            .branch(
                Update::filter_message()
                    .filter_command::<Command>()
                    .endpoint(answer),
            )
            .branch(Update::filter_message().endpoint(message_handler)),
    )
    .enable_ctrlc_handler()
    .build()
    .dispatch()
    .await;

...

async fn message_handler(bot: Bot, msg: Message) -> ResponseResult<()> {
    bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, "could not handle message")
        .await?;
    Ok(())
}
```